# linux c shared memory:why the order of contents are opposite when write and read

Tags: c, ipc

I wanna use int array in shared memory,after writing 1,2,3 into it,I expect read it like this:1,2,3.But I read this:3,2,1.I don't know why

```
write code:
int *gIn;
int main(){
    int id;
    id = shmget(0x666,1024,IPC_CREAT|0666);
    gIn=(int *)shmat(id,NULL,0);

    *gIn++=10;
    *gIn++=20;
    *gIn++=30;
    sleep(10);
    return 0;
}

read code:
int *gIn;
int main(){
    int id;
    id = shmget(0x666,1024,IPC_CREAT|0666);
    gIn=(int *)shmat(id,NULL,0);

    printf("%d|%d|%d\n",*gIn++,*gIn++,*gIn++);
    return 0;
}
```

I expect the output of read process to be 10|20|30,but the actual output is 30|20|10.It's very strange.I don't know why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line: `printf("%d|%d|%d\n",*gIn++,*gIn++,*gIn++);`. The order of evaluation for the parameters to `printf` is implementation defined. In your case it just happens to do this in an order you didn't expect.

Suggest you pull out the values separately before the `printf` in local variables (or an array) and then print the value.

Comment: ... or `printf("%d|", *gIn++); printf("%d|", *gIn++); printf("%d\n", *gIn++);`.

Comment: I can't image any order can lead to this result..could you explain more specifically,thank you.

Comment: @wwwpy666 The output from `#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  int someMemory[3] = {1, 2, 3};
  int *gIn = someMemory;  printf("First attempt: %d %d %d\n", *gIn++, *gIn++, *gIn);
  gIn = someMemory;  printf("Second attempt: %d ", *gIn++);  printf("%d ", *gIn++);  printf("%d\n", *gIn);
}`is either `First attempt: 2 1 1
Second attempt: 1 2 3` (as on my Intel/linux/gcc machine) OR `First attempt: 1 2 3
Second attempt: 1 2 3`. Both outputs are valid.